# QGIS Gaussian Filter

Tags: qgis, saga, filter

I am optimistically hoping someone can shed some light on this. I am trying to apply a gaussian/low pass filter to a raster dataset. I naively applied the SAGA Gaussian Filter in QGIS to the below, using circle type with a distance of 5 cells, but it adds in a region with positive cells that I cannot explain the addition on the edge case. The first is the input (Green is 0) and the second is the output with the highlights area I can't understand the addition given the input grid has nothing proximal to justify (based on my understanding) its inclusion. Input operation in the final image.

Happy to move to an alternate environment if SAGA is not appropriate to correct this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to say anything without test data.